# Stop all ECS Cluster tasks with AWS CLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ecs, aws-cli

Self answers:How to stop all tasks on a cluster with a single cli command, easily allowing for extra parameters to be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below will:

1. Get all the tasks in the cluster
2. Select the task arns using `jq`, `-r` removes the quotes from the
   json value.
3. Pass each arn to the next command using `xargs`, the value is
   appended to the command (after --task). `n-1` just ensures there is
   one command per arn, not sure if necessary.

`aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "$ecs_cluster" | jq -r ".taskArns[]" | xargs -n1 aws ecs stop-task --no-cli-pager --cluster "$ecs_cluster" --task`

`--no-cli-pager` prevents the output from `stop-task` from getting stuck after each execution.

Any optimization welcome. I saw another solution with awk but found it hard to use with passing extra params to the second command.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to get Baron's answer to work and found that it needed an adjustment to work in my AWS CodeBuild (Ubuntu) use case by pulling the task id out of the ARN:

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "${clustername}" | jq -r ".taskArns[] | split(\"/\")[2]" | xargs -n1 aws ecs stop-task --no-cli-pager --cluster "${clustername}" --task
```

You might also want to stop all tasks for only one service

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster "${clustername}" --service "${servicename}" | jq -r ".taskArns[] | split(\"/\")[2]" | xargs -n1 aws ecs stop-task --no-cli-pager --cluster "${clustername}" --task
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with `Windows Powershell`:

```
$arns = aws ecs list-tasks --cluster YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME --service YOUR_SERVICE_NAME --query "taskArns" | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($arn in $arns) { aws ecs stop-task --no-cli-pager --cluster YOUR_CLUSTER_NAME --task $arn}
```